# Big integer division with operands aproximately of the same size

Tags: c++, biginteger, arbitrary-precision, multiprecision

I'm trying to implement a function that computes the division between two numbers approximately of the same size. I use an array of `unsigned int`'s to store the values of each number (see below the class structure). I want to implement an efficient division function for the case when the difference between the number of `unsigned int`'s of both is not bigger than 1. I've looked into the long division algorithm (as described in wikipedia), but it's too slow. Is there any efficient algorithm that deals with this special case? At the moment, I'm dealing with numbers with up to 100 digits.

```
class BigInt {
public:
    short sign; //sign of the number
    unsigned int size; //number of unsigned int's needed to store the number
    unsigned int* values; //values of the number

    ...
}
```

Thanks

Comment: There are MP libraries, why not use one of them instead of rolling your own?

Comment: @Barmar: Because you can't ask about libraries on SO?

Comment: @ScottHunter You can't ask for recommendations but if the OP picks a library and then has question about how to use it those are OT as long as the are not too broad or opinion based.

Comment: Why do you think "approximately the same size" is a useful basis for finding a better algorithm?  It means the result will be small.  But it also means the ordinary algorithm has less work to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a modified version of Knuth's algorithm D (The Art of Computer Programming Vol.2, Section 4.3.1) ought to do the trick in constant average time for random input, with a linear time worst-case. Significant simplifications stem from only requiring the first quotient word produced by the initial iteration.

Below is my attempt at unashamedly adapting the generic [implementation from Hacker's Delight](http://www.hackersdelight.org/hdcodetxt/divmnu.c.txt). The implementation assumes 32-bit words and 64-bit intermediates/division but may be naturally extended where wider arithmetic is available.

I do fear that the function is virtually untested however so please treat this more as the germ of an idea as opposed to a fully-fledged implementation. To be honest I don't even remember the subtleties of *why* the algorithm works.

```
// A helper function for finding the position of the most significant set bit.
// Please plug in your intrinsic of choice here
static unsigned int find_first_bit(uint32_t value) {
#   ifdef _MSC_VER
    unsigned long index;
    (void) _BitScanReverse(&index, value);
    return index + 1;
#   else
    unsigned int count = 0;
    for(count = 0; value; ++count)
        value >>= 1;
    return count;
#   endif
}

// Multi-word division in 32-bit big-endian segments, returning the most significant
// word of the quotient.
uint32_t divide(const uint32_t *num, const uint32_t *den, size_t len) {
    // Skip past leading zero denominator digits. The quotient must fit in a single
    // 32-bit word and so only the preceeding numerator digit needs be examined
    uint32_t norm_den;
    uint64_t norm_num = 0;
    size_t top = 0;
    while(norm_den = den[top], !norm_den)
        norm_num = num[top++];
    // Please pad the input to insure at least three denominator words counting from
    // the first non-zero digit
    assert(len >= top + 3);
    // Divide the first two digits of the numerator by the leading digit of the
    // denominator as an initial quotient digit guess, yielding an upper bound
    // for the quotient at most two steps above the true value.
    // Simultaneously normalize the denominator with the MSB in the 31st bit.
    unsigned int norm = find_first_bit(norm_den);
    norm_num = norm_num << (64 - norm);
    norm_num |= ((uint64_t) num[top + 0] << 32 | num[top + 1]) >> norm;
    norm_den = ((uint64_t) norm_den << 32 | den[top + 1]) >> norm;
    // We are using a straight 64/64 division where 64/32=32 would suffice. The latter
    // is available on e.g. x86-32 but difficult to generate short of assembly code.
    uint32_t quot = (uint32_t) (norm_num / norm_den);
    // Substitute norm_num - quot * norm_den if your optimizer is too thick-headed to
    // efficiently extract the remainder
    uint32_t rem = norm_num % norm_den;
    // Test the next word of the input, reducing the upper bound to within one step
    // of the true quotient. See Knuth for proofs of this reduction and the bounds
    // of the first guess
    norm_num = ((uint64_t) num[top + 1] << 32 | num[top + 2]) >> norm;
    norm_num = (uint64_t) rem << 32 | (uint32_t) norm_num;
    norm_den = ((uint64_t) den[top + 1] << 32 | den[top + 2]) >> norm;
    if((uint64_t) quot * norm_den > norm_num) {
        --quot;
        // There is no "add-back" step try to avoid and so there is little point
        // in looping to refine the guess further since the bound is sufficiently
        // tight already
    }
    // Compare quotient guess multiplied by the denominator to the numerator
    // across whole numbers to account for the final quotient step.
    // There is no need to bother with normalization here. Furthermore we can
    // compare from the most to the least significant and cut off early when the
    // intermediate result becomes large, yielding a constant average running
    // time for random input
    uint64_t accum = 0;
    do {
        uint64_t prod = (uint64_t) quot * *den++;
        accum = accum << 32 | *num++;
        // A negative partial result can never recover, so pick the lower
        // quotient. A separate test is required to avoid 65-bit arithmetic
        if(accum < prod)
            return --quot;
        accum -= prod;
        // Similarly a partial result which spills into the upper 32-bits can't
        // recover either, so go with the upper quotient
        if((uint64_t) accum >= 0x100000000)
            return quot;
    } while(--len);
    return quot;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I implemented this on my code and its working when both operands have the same size. Can this also be adapted to the case where the numerator has 1 more unsigned int than the denominator, but its most significant bit is smaller than the most significant bit or the denominator?

Comment: @fc67: It depends, how wide are your integers and is the maximum integer size supported by your compiler? A wider numerator may yield quotients up to two integers in width, requiring 4-integer wide intermediate calculations. In any event I did take a stab at handling the leading-zero case where the quotient is assumed to still fit in a single word.

Comment: Thank you again. Regarding our question, the difference between the numerator and the denominator is always such that the quotient fits in an unsigned int. By the way, should this algorithm always compute the exact value of the division or only an approximation? There are cases where I get the value 1 or 2 units above or below the correct result.

Comment: @fc67: The algorithm is exact, yes, though as mentioned my untested implementation of it is very likely buggy. Can you post the failing cases? The more general point is that the classic long-division algorithm reduces to something rather efficient for this particular special case.

Comment: For example in this case: 3782738416563008660212309337022188620417599142349469355984513962389661 / 920336366175677376777359893372676601458067846583151108088345 the result is 4110169451, which is the rounded up value of the exact result (I need the truncated values as in a normal integer division). And on this case 7002706679272468777054082039994118629191191118861803934204041953 / 14170981619797660398828784523106536754838827785935839608, I get 494158191 which is 2 units below the correct truncated result.

Comment: @fc67: It seems I had forgotten to truncate the denominator word to 32-bits in the second stage, I also dropped the loop there since it gains us nothing in this specialized case. Beware that it's still not properly tested though. Oh, and C compilers are generally abysmal at taking advantage of multi-precision arithmetic instructions (carry flags, irregular precision instructions, modular shifts, etc) and so getting decent constant factors will likely requires careful hand-holding and intrinsics or assembly code if you are targeting a 32-bit architecture.

Comment: The algorithm is still rounding up on the mentioned case (didn't test for others yet). Unfortunately I don't have access to Knuth's book. Could you be so kind to explain me how the algorithm works exactly, so it would make it easier for me to find such kind of bugs? Additionally, I uploaded my code to pastebin [link](http://pastebin.com/kHi2LkqA). My numbers are represented in a least significant first fashion, which means that the first value of the array is the least significant. I would appreciate it if you could take a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: @fc67: The `norm_den` variable needs to be truncated by using the narrow type. Have a go at using the original code as-is, transcribing the numbers into a correctly big-endian buffers as a starting point. As for Knuth I'd suggest checking whether your local library can get hold of it for you, I find they are usually very helpful in these matters. Beyond that I'd also suggest taking a look at the known-good Hacker's Delight implementation and simplifying it for this case to see whether you end up with the same method.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want an integer result, you should be able to carry this out fairly fast.

It's probably easiest to think of this in decimal terms with slightly smaller numbers to start with.

Let's consider somewhat smaller numbers, like: 123456789/54321876. One of these has one more digit than the other, so the largest possible result is somewhere around 10.

If we divide both sides so we have (say) three digits left in the larger number and two digits in the smaller one, we get `123/54`, which yields the same integer result as if we'd done the work to full precision throughout.

In your case, you can do pretty much the same except instead of decimal digits, you'll keep basically three words of precision in your larger item and two words in the smaller (and in actuality, even that's being conservative--2 and 1 words respectively is *probably* sufficient, but I'm too lazy to prove that right now, and if you do that, you may need to be more careful with rounding as well).

So yes, your idea that this is kind of a special case where you can save work based on the numbers being nearly the same size was correct.

Comment: "probably" sufficient is not actually sufficient.  Having more "words" both unnecessarily adds cost and fails to guarantee correctness.  So 2/1 is not enough, while 3/2 is both too many and not enough.

Comment: what kind of "correctness" are you talking about here when (we assume) the division is integer? it will necessarily lose precision. So it is "probably" sufficient in this case.

Comment: @JSF: your argument would be much more effective if you pointed to a concrete example of failure.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: Consider 222222/111111 vs 222221/111111 or 222222/111112. To get the correctly rounded result you potentially need to evaluate down to the least significant digit, though you can stop early as long as the error bounds don't straddle an integer quotient.

Comment: @doynax: All your examples have the same number of digits in the numerator and the denominator, which (by the algorithm I suggested) would always evaluate to the least significant digit. to fit with this, we'd need something like `222222/11112` producing the wrong answer. To decide that, I believe we'd need to know whether he wants the result truncated or rounded.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: Sorry, I was attempting to simplify the example to clarify the issue. Unfortunately whatever round scheme chosen merely shifts the point which the partially evaluated result can't be allowed to straddle. Consider 1222220/222222 vs 1222221/222222.

Comment: @doynax: Yeah, sounds about right. In a lot of cases, you can come up with the right answer pretty quickly by computing both the largest possible value (numerator rounded up, denominator rounded down) and smallest possible value (vice versa). If they agree, you clearly have the right answer. Then carry the computation out to full precision when/if they disagree.